# How to count the number of duplicate rows but return only the values of distinct in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to use SQLite's `count()` function to calculate the quantity of items for each distinct item in a store's inventory.

I have started off by creating an "inventory" table where each row represent different store locations.

*Table of storefronts:*

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stores (" +
        "_id              INTEGER            PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "timestamp        DATETIME           DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP " +
        //many other columns (eg. address, state, phone...)
        ");");
```

I then created a table which contains a list of all the items where `_store_id` is basically pointing to the primary key in the "stores" table.

*Table of item barcode scan information:*

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item_scans (" +
        "_id              INTEGER            PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "_store_id        INTEGER," +
        "item_code        VARCHAR " +
        ");");
```

---

**Attempt to retrieve inventory information for a specific store:**

To start I tried a simple query to get a list of all items that have been scanned relating to a particular storefront (the variable `sid` is used to select the store's primary key)

*Query:*

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _store_id, item_code " +
                " FROM item_inventory" + 
                " WHERE _store_id = " + String.valueOf(sid),
        null);
```

Which produces a result where all items (including duplicates) are returned.

*Result:*

```
 0 {
    _store_id=14
    item_code=852874006301
 }
 1 {
    _store_id=14
    item_code=852874006301
 }
 2 {
    _store_id=14
    item_code=041570110461
 }
```

I then *tried* to count the number of occurrences of each item and return results containing only distinct `item_code` rows, but I also include a new column called `item_inventory` which should be a count of the quantity of how many identical `item_code` entries were present for the given `sid`.

*Query:*

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT t1._store_id, t1.item_code, t2.item_quantity " +
                " FROM item_invnetory t1 " +
                " INNER JOIN (SELECT _store_id, item_code, count(item_code) AS item_quantity " +
                        " FROM item_inventory" +
                        " WHERE _store_id = " + String.valueOf(sid) +
                ") t2 " +
                " ON t1._store_id = t2._store_id " +
                " WHERE t1._store_id = " + String.valueOf(sid),
        null);
```

This gives me a list of distinct items but the value for `item_inventory` is incorrect and appears as though its calculating the total quantity of all items for a particular store:

*Result:*

```
 0 {
    _store_id=14
    item_code=041570110461
    item_quantity=3
 }
 1 {
    _store_id=14
    item_code=852874006301
    item_quantity=3
 }
```

What I really was hoping to achieve was to use an SQLite query where `item_inventory` was the value of the total number of items for each distinct item at a store location.

*Example of desired result:*

```
 0 {
    _store_id=14
    item_code=041570110461
    item_quantity=1
 }
 1 {
    _store_id=14
    item_code=852874006301
    item_quantity=2
 }
```

I apologize for my lack of experience with SQLite, I do not often get to use `inner join` and/or `distinct` nor do I use much of raw queries in general but my boss asked me to create a project using Android and display everything in a ListView.

Comment: Why the MySQL tag? Please provide the original sample data that would produce desired output. (Also see [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125))

Comment: Total typo on the MySQL tag! Thanks for pointing that out. Also thanks for the tip on SQL table formatting!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [GROUP BY clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) for this, no need to use JOIN or DISTINCT.

```
SELECT item_code, COUNT(*) as item_quantity
FROM item_inventory
WHERE _store_id = ?
GROUP BY item_code
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much! I love StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the same problem using the below code:

```
String query = "SELECT violationDate, COUNT(*) as date " +
            "FROM challan " +
            "WHERE challanType = '" + type + "' GROUP BY violationDate";
```

Here violationDate and date are two columns of the result table. date column will return occurrence.

```
cr.getInt(1)
```